# DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration in DataProtection does not work for current user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a console application named Keycreator that is used to create key using DataProtection.I am using ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG() extension for key configuration. Here's a snippet for the same:

```
 var securityIdentifiers = identities.Select(identity => $"SID={new NTAccount(identity).Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier))}");
dataProtectionBuilder.ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG(string.Join(" OR ", securityIdentifiers), flags: DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
```

The key generation works as expected.

There is another console app named DataProtector that takes in the key as one of the parameter that is generated using the keycreator console to encrypt/decrypt the file.

Working scenario: When I pass in identities to generate key that includes the current user ,the data protection exe works as expected ie .the encrypt/decrypt of the file being passed works with no issue.

Problem Area: When passing in identities excluding the current user, the data protection creates a new key that is unencrypted even though the encrypted key is already available.
There is an extension to disable Automatic Key Generation
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionbuilderextensions.disableautomatickeygeneration?view=aspnetcore-6.0][1]

but even with the extension dataprotection application creates an unencrypted key file.

The Point that i am trying to convey is ,this **unencrypted key creation issue exists only when the key that is generated in the keycreator console does not include the current user as one of the identity.**

Here is the error that is thrown:

The key ring does not contain a valid default protection key. **The data protection system cannot create a new key because auto-generation of keys is disabled**. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Farhin Shaikh, Do you mean identity must contains current user? how do you configure your `current user`?

Comment: Yes. I pass in the login credentials of the user from the system(can be an admin/user) from where the console application